# How do I increase the number of lines shown on the Ubuntu terminal window?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I am [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) developer. I have run a Ruby on Rails server in the terminal window. Ruby on Rails outputs log information into the terminal windows. But due to the long log, the first log lines are inaccessible for me through window scrolling.

How could I increase the number of lines shown in the terminal window?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Click <kbd>Edit</kbd>→<kbd>Profiles</kbd>→<kbd>Scrolling</kbd>. Then increase the value under <kbd>limit scrollback to:</kbd> or untick it to allow scrolling through unlimited lines.

[image: Terminal Preferences]

From comment by Kevin: Be careful with unchecking that option. If a program goes crazy and spews lots of data onto your terminal, you could have memory issues.

Comment: or just untick?

Comment: Be careful with unchecking that option entirely.  If a program goes crazy and spews lots of data onto your terminal, you could have memory issues.

Comment: Good advice. Have some upvotes @Kevin :D But I never mentioned unticking >:-D A.B did >:D

Comment: Good advice, but can this also be done from command line. This advice is not possible for me, since I do not have a desktop (I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as a windows subsystem for linux, wsl).

Answer (score 7):

Open the profile settings for the terminal via

> *Edit* > *Profile Settings*.

Or with a right click in the terminal:

> *Profile* > *Profile Settings*

Change the value for `Limit scrollback` or remove the mark for unlimited scrolling.

Comment: Mine got a picture >:-D

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about this in a different way, you could also redirect the output to a file and then use `less +F` to stream the file into `less`. Pressing `ctrl + c` will stop the stream, and typing `shift + f` will continue the stream.

This also gives you the added benefit of being able to highlight things you care about. For example, typing `/my_search_term` (forward-search) or `?my_search_term` (backward-search) will also highlight `my_search_term` in the file. This highlighting will continue as new data streams in.

**How do I output to a file?**
There are a couple of options, but for completeness, this may be best:

```
start_rails_server &>> my_new_logfile
```

The `&>` will pipe both the stdout *and* stderr to the log file. (You can pick one or the other by using a number, `1` for stdout and `2` for stderr, though stdout is implicit so you could just do `cmd > file` and you would get stdout printed to your file.)

The angle bracket sends the output to `my_new_logfile`, and the fact that there are two means that it will append to the file if it exists, and create a new one if not. If you used a single angle bracket, then any existing file would be overwritten:

```
start_rails_server &> my_new_logfile
```